# Rails helper to return <li> for each category actually returning hash of categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I'm trying to clean up my views and be more DRY by using helpers. Starting with what seems like a simple one to return an li for each category.

```
def showcats
  Category.all.each do |cat|
    content_tag(:li, link_to(cat.title, cat))
  end
end
```

I've tried calling it in erb and haml using either

```
<%= showcats %>
```

or

```
= showcats
```

and each time I get back this mess when the page renders:

```
[#<Category id: 1, title: "First Category", description: "This is the description of the first category", created_at: "2014-02-18 02:05:37", updated_at: "2014-02-18 02:05:37">, #<Category id: 2, title: "Second Category", description: "This is the description of the second category", created_at: "2014-02-18 02:05:37", updated_at: "2014-02-18 02:05:37">,
```

and so on...

I've tried it with changing the showcats helper to require a variable, and passing that along, like "showcats(@categories)" but the same thing persists. If I put "return" in front of content_tag it will not show the hash of all categories, but it only returns a single category link, which I think is to be expected.

I've read quite a few questions on SO and other places around the web and I can't see where my mistake is. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The each function is returning all the categories. So change the each method to map instead.

Comment: That seems to have done it. I  had to add .join to the end of the loop to get it to display properly, prior to that it was a hash of links, but now I'm getting the proper li output. Thanks! I choose you, Charizard_!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `showcats` method as shown below:

```
def showcats
  Category.all.collect do |cat|
    content_tag(:li, link_to(cat.title, cat))
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

`collect` : Returns a `new array` with the results of running block once for every element in enum whereas,

`each` : Returns the object on which each is called.